# How do art historians study the transactions of art merchants?

Tags: art, book, modern, venice

**My question is the following**: I would like to ask **how to frame a research paper about transactions of art merchants** and their transcription from the accounting book to a research paper. I would like to be able to have a general idea of how *a report of an art accounting book should be written in the literature* (how long the introductory part should be, how much time to focus on the mere descriptive part and if I should focus more on this or whether I should dig deeper in the life of some specific families that appear many times on the accounting book,...).

More details about my question:

I am analyzing and summarizing a whole art accounting book of some northern-Italian merchants of the late XVII century and I have to describe all the material they bought and sold over a period of 5 years. Besides a purely descriptive work, I was trying to figure out also the main facts about some specific families that appear more frequently on the accounting books.

More precisely, I am working on an old XVII century-book in which a rich aristocratic family of Venice took notes of all the material they sold, the names of the buyers, the name of the painting or the statue sold, the date and the price. At the beginning the work is purely descriptive: I have to digitalize the whole accounting book to have a digital version of it. Then, the work will continue by describing the merchants I am analyzing, the work I did on their accounting book and it will end with a specific research on the most frequent buyers and their lives.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is the main point! I am looking for methodologies mostly and my thoughts are that I may be able to learn them by reading what art historians write (and how they write it) about transactions of art merchants. This is why I was looking for published work in art history academic journals of researches similar to mine (and this is why I would consider as a satisfactory answer also a good citation of a paper about transactions of art merchants). In any case, thanks for the editing and your kind effort to make my question clearer and in line with the guidelines of HSE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Exchange is not a resource-location site.

Comment: A reference would be a good proxy for my answer, but in general I am asking how to frame a research paper about transactions of art merchants and their transcription from the accounting book to a research paper. I think that it should be on topic from this point of view.

Comment: "but in general I am asking **how to frame a research paper** about transactions of art merchants and their transcription from the accounting book to a research paper."
Maybe AcademiaSE is a better fit?

Comment: I take your point, but they closed the question as well, saying it is too specific as a research and should be posted here :(

Comment: I support re-opening this question; I believe that OP has resolved the reference request.  I believe this aligns with [discussion on meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4132/1401), and I believe that discussion of historical methods is within the scope of H:SE.

Comment: Is this within the discipline of Art History, or general history, economic history, etc? Do you have any guidelines or limitations or purpose: are you studying some discipline, have you been engaged to research this specific document, are you looking to publish, writing a PhD proposal...? If art history, you would normally expect to relate the history and provenance of certain works to their content and style, and provide some sort of argument about the meaning, purpose, function, etc, of those works, based on the details of the transactions.

Comment: I have trouble understanding why this is tagged and focussed only on 'art' when I read *more* of an 'economics' content around this. You take the src 'accounting book' then describe transactions and people involved? The goods maybe 'art', but unless you also take specifics of these goods into analysis, it might well be some research that may do completely without the 'art' angle (as in 'accounting books work for anything, whether grain, labour, or narcotics'? Or, if there are certain specifics that may arise from 'art', could you explain what those might be for your topic?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The tag-'issue' isn't for open/close, but for the scope & focus of the Q itself. An 'art' focus prompts me to think of paintings showing economic activity, 'economics' shows more of the accounting book-side itself. For a general hint into that latter Bruno Frey [Economics of Art & Culture](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-15748-7) (several books by him, the references in them should be worth it) or Antonelli [Art and Accounting History…](https://doi.org/10.1080/09585200601127822)? My understanding of the Q is lacking, I invite Son or any other user to fill the A-box below.

Comment: LangLangC, you are right, but the main focus on art is because the final work I'm RAing will be published in some art journals since the work will be at the end about the art collection we found. Nevertheless, at this first stage, I have to write some reports that have to be considered as articles themselves, and I would like to follow the structure of art historians' projects that start from the accounting books and describe the whole art collection they find, trying to research about the history of an aristocratic family of the time.

Comment: Personally, I still do not comprehend the actual question here. Appears to me you are on track with most methodical steps, but may be missing your own "research question" (the 'how to frame' in bounty text). My guess: it all depends on *that:* *what do you want to know from those books?* If it's still purely exploratory (what do I see, find, may I conclude from these)—that's a fine first approach. Now, I might give you some more example papers I think go into such directions. But that's imo not a good answer here. If you think those might help you, head to [chat] & ping me for links to those.